# Stock 10 Speed Shifters with 9 Speed Transmission

Tags: derailleur-rear, cable, sram, campagnolo

I have a bike that was built with 10 Speed Campagnolo Veloce Shifters, 9 speed Veloce rear derailleur, and SRAM 9 speed cassette and chain.

I found a [page](http://www.rodbikes.com/articles/9-10sp.html) on the builder's website that states they do this on purpose and that with proper cable adjustment, it works.

I've spent hours trying to get the adjustment right but some gears always slip from the indexing being off.

Thanks!

Comment: The easiest answer is to keep everything in the same brand and groupset.  The rear shifter probably won't care, but it may expect a different cable pull.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not changing any parts. These are the stock parts so I know this setup worked at one time. I'm simply wanting to adjust the cable in such a way that the 10th index is past the biggest cog but the other index positions are spot on so all the cogs on the cassette work. Please let me know if there's easier ways to communicate about this, I've been having a hard time finding good info.

Comment: Do you know that the setup worked only because they are the stock parts? Or do you have first hand experience that it actually worked.

Comment: I edited the original question to include a link to the builder's explanation of the mixed parts.

Comment: I'm surprised they mixed the speeds like that. Did the bike also come with instructions not to use the first/last gear on the shifter?

Comment: The manufacturer almost got it right. The combination they seem to be after is 10 speed Campy shifter, 9 speed Shimano derailleur, 9 speed Shimano cassette and alternate cable routing. I doubt the setup has ever worked.

Comment: 9 and 10 speed cassettes have different cog spacing, so not just using one cog doesn't work.

Comment: What is supposed to happen with the extra position on the shifter?  Does it appear at the top or bottom of the range?

Comment: Based on spending hours researching this, I'm led to believe one can place the extra position beyond the largest cog by tuning it that way, I'm now just trying to figure out exactly how that's accomplished. Just the right cable tension?

Comment: Extra position on the shifter is never the/a problem and read herring in this case. Tune the Dérailleur High/Low screws and the shifter cannot reach it.

Comment: This seems like a pretty inane setup -- you've spent all the money except for the Campy 10 speed except for the campy rear wheel. And you've opted for a much more expensive option than running all Shimano/Sram 9 speed with nothing to gain.

Comment: I got it used so the frame or wheelset alone are worth more than what I paid. I'll replace parts as needed or as I'm able.

Comment: FWIW, I have this setup on one of my bikes and it works just fine for me. If you prefer the ergonomics of Campy 10spd and the cassette options available with Shimano/Sram 9spd, it's a viable solution.

Comment: I adjusted mine such that the "extra" click was on the smallest cog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not entirely surprised you have problems [refer here...](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bicycles/Maintenance_and_Repair/Gear-changing_Dimensions)

According to this link, Cable Pull for a Campy 10 shifter is 2.8mm, dérailleur ratio for a Campy is 1.5 (or 1.4 for old) Cassette sprocket pitch for SRam 9 is 4.35.

So a single shift on the the 10speed is 2.8*1.5 = 4.2mm (ideal is 4.35). Over a 9 speeds that an error of 1.35mm, so when tuning, you will end up with about 0.7mm error on the outer cogs - i.e. it will never be able to be tuned perfectly, but when everything is new and shiny, will work surprisingly well. As things get less new and shiny, this error means tuning become more and more difficult.

The fix would be installed a Campy 9 speed shifter or a 10 Speed cassette and chain.

Edit: Another page on compatibility [here](http://blog.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/) lead me to 
[This adapter (Shiftmate)](http://www.jtekengineering.com/resources/shiftmate-compatibility/) or similar might be the answer you are looking for. They specifically list a Campy 10 shifter to Shimno 9 (Sram and Shitmano 9 speed are the same).

Comment: Thanks! Would you please repost the link? It's linking to this question currently. I wouldn't necessarily mind getting a 10 Speed cassette and chain as I'd like some different gears anyway but would I need a 10 speed derailleur also?

Comment: Is it not possible to push this error to the 10th cog (that isn't there)?

Comment: 1.35mm is a lot. In my experience, a quarter turn of a barrel cable adjuster can sometimes make quite a difference in shifting: like from instant to a delay of a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks, I've been considering the shiftmate and I think that's what I'll do if the builder's instructions don't work for me.